# What is the best way to connect a .NET Core desktop application to a Azure SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, security, asp.net-web-api

I am building a desktop application in .NET Core.  I will connect this application to an Azure SQL server.  The information that will pass between the two is very sensitive.  Each query to the database can return a response of a few kilobytes to 4 MB.  When executing queries on the SQL server I would like to know the login \ identity of the user making the request so that I can return only the data this user is allowed to see.

I am trying to decide between connecting my desktop application directly to the Azure SQL database or creating Web APIs.

My Questions Are:

1. Which would you recommend, connecting directly to the Azure SQL Database or using a Web API that connects to the database on the server?
2. I know it is bad practice to hard code the user name and password to the SQL server in my application.  If I connect directly to the SQL server would I have to create an account on the SQL server for each user and ask the user for their credentials when they login and then pass it to the SQL server?
3. If I use a Web API how do I obtain the users credentials?  Again, do I have to set up individual accounts for each user? Would I do this using OAuth or some other method? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api
4. Would anyone endorse using WCF Data Service instead?

Comment: Hi there! Your question is too broad. Here, on stackoverflow, we dealing with coding issues, so if you have a problem with your code (exceptions, unpredictable behavior, etc.) - edit your question or ask another one. You may also find this link useful: [ask]

Comment: Ok. Sorry.  Is there a way for me to delete the question?

Comment: try this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

1. No, this is a potential security risk if you make your SQL Database publicly available. There is an [identity provider for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) you can decide weather you want to store the users in the DB or you can also use external login providers like Facebook, Google, or Microsoft.
2. If you want to do this, you should use [Azure Active Directory Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication) you can use it to authenticate users for your application and for the Azure SQL Database both. But, this can work if you do B2B applications, or and internal app for your company. If you want to have a public application available on the internet, and let everybody to register you should go with the first solution.
3. It is described in the [identity provider for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) article.
4. You can't, if you check the [Choosing between .NET Core and .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server) article, it says "WCF server implementation is currently only available in the .NET Framework" only the client is implemented in .NET Core.